# Type of a lambda function, using auto

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, types

I am trying to write a c++ lambda function, and don't like having to use `auto` as the type. Currently it looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
//  Sends the address of an integer to a function which prints out the contents;
    auto print_int = [](int* a) {std::cout << *a << std::endl;};
    int a;
    a = 3;
    print_int(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I would like to change the `auto` to something like `std::function<void(int)>` but am not sure how. The answers to

- [What is the type of a lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161219/what-is-the-type-of-a-lambda-function)

seems relevant, but I am not sure how to adapt it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `std::function<void(int)> = [](int * a) {std::cout << *a << std::endl;};`?

Comment: The concrete type name of the lambda function is not specified by standard. Nor should you care about it when a lambda is really called for.

Comment: What exactly about `auto` is the problem?

Comment: As a side note, if you really care about the type name (I don't see why you would), and your lambda is captureless, you can just assign it to a regular function pointer.

Comment: So, you prefer a potential allocation because type `auto` hurts you in a way I didn't even understand? What's the actual issue?

Comment: I'm uneasy with using auto as it is more likely to compile, where I would want to be more specific about that type of function I would like `print_int` to be.

Comment: IMO, you should just use `auto` and let the compiler do what it does. Even with polymorphism, templates, the auto keyword, etc, C++ is still a strongly typed language and the compiler will still ensure that whatever print_int is, it is something that resembles a function that is willing to take something that resembles a pointer to int. There will be no run-time surprises.   ---   The one run-time surprise you _will_ get with this code is the access violation/seg fault you get when you try to `*a = 3` with `a` uninitialised.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lambdas are meant to be used with either `auto` or as template parameter. You never know the type of a lambda and you can't type it. Each lambda has it's own unique type. Even if you knew the name of the type, their type names usually contains character prohibited in type names.

Why does lambda have their own type? because in reality, the compiler create a class defined a bit like that:

```
struct /* unnamed */ {

    // function body
    auto operator()(int* a) const {
        std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    }

} print_int; // <- instance name
```

This code is very close to an equivalent (I omitted conversion operator).
As you can see, you already use auto, because lambdas are deducing the return type.

Some will say to use `std::function<void(int*)>`, but I disagree. `std::function` is a polymorphic wrapper around anything callable. Since lambdas are callable types, they fit into it. I other words, it work much like `std::any` but with a call operator. It will induce overhead in your application.

**So what should you do?**

use `auto`! `auto` isn't bad. In fact, it can even make your code faster and reduce unnecessary typing. If you feel uncomfortable with `auto`, well you shouldn't! `auto` is great, especially if you don't have the choice ;)

In fact, you could avoid using `auto` by using a template parameter:

```
template<typename F, typename Arg>
void parametric_print(F function, Arg&& arg) {
    function(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    parametric_print([](int* a) {std::cout << *a << std::endl;}, &a);
}
```

There you go, no `auto`! However, a template parameter is deduced with the same rule as `auto`. In fact, concept are accepted into the C++20 standard with terse function templates. You could write the same function template like this:

```
// C++20
void parametric_print(auto function, auto&& arg) {
    function(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
}
```

As mentionned by Oktalist, if concepts are accepted into the standard, then you could replace `auto` with `Callable`:

```
Callable print_int = [](int* a) { std::cout << *a << std::endl; };
```

But it does not result in a different type, it just enforce some rules when deducing the type.

Comment: If concepts are accepted, you could do exactly what OP wants with `Callable print_int = [](int* a){...};` Until then, `auto` is just a more permissive version of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
int a;
[](int* a) {std::cout << *a << std::endl;}(&a);
```

No `auto` used.

---

> However, I would like to change the auto to something like `std::function<void(int)>` but am not sure how.

That is certainly possible. `std::functional` has a templated converting constructor. You simply pass the lambda to the constructor and that's all there is to it. Also, you'll need to fix the argument type since your lambda expects an `int*`, not an `int` (this is the kind of bug that `auto` fixes *automatically*).

```
std::function<void(int*)> print_int = [](int* a) {std::cout << *a << std::endl;};
```

Note however that there are two drawbacks to this.

- `std::function` wrapper is an indirection layer that hides the actual type of the callable object. This wrapper layer adds runtime overhead and prevents some optimizations.
- You have to manually update the type if you make changes to the return value, or arguments of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda has its own unnamed type.

Your may convert your lambda into `std::function<void(int*)>`
(or for captureless lambda to `void (*)(int*)`).

You may create your functor explicitly so you give it a name, something like:

```
class Print_int
{
public:
    void operator()(int* a) const {std::cout << *a << std::endl;}
};
```

and then

```
Print_int print_int;
```

Comment: Looking to avoid making classes.