# different types in operator ? with no-capture, same signature, lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

According to the c++ standard, a lambda function has a unique type, hence in general two lambdas cannot be used in conjunction with the `?` operator. However, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121441/type-of-a-lambda-function-using-auto), a lambda with no capture can be converted to a function pointer. Hence, the following code correctly compiles:

```
int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    auto a_lambda = x ? [](int p) { } : [](int p) { };
}
```

However, if the argument of the lambda is declared `auto`

```
int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    auto a_lambda = x ? [](auto p)  { } : [](auto p) { };
}
```

the code no longer compiles, giving error:

```
main.cpp:4:23: error: operands to ?: have different types 'main()::<lambda(auto:1)>' and 'main()::<lambda(auto:2)>'

    4 |     auto a_lambda = x ? [](auto p)  { } : [](auto p) { };
```

The code also does not compile if I force the assignment to a function with parameter `int`:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    // error: operands to ?: have different types 'main()::<lambda(auto:1)>' and 'main()::<lambda(auto:2)>'
    std::function<void(int)> a_lambda = x ? [](auto p)  { } : [](auto p) { };
}
```

With the assignement to a function with given signature, the `auto` in the parameter list should be for both lambdas deduced as `int`.

- Why have the two lambdas still a different type?
- Is there a way to fix the second code, i.e., is it possible to "choose" with the `?` operator between two lambdas that have an `auto` in the parameter list, if I am sure that for both lambdas the `auto` will be deduced to the same type?

Comment: If you're sure what the deduced type will be, then what's the issue with stating it explicitly?

Comment: `auto a_lambda = x ? function<void(int)>([](auto p)  { }) : function<void(int)>([](auto p) { });`

Comment: @cigien Just like any other ```auto```, it is sometime easier to use it instead of "sorting out" the type, when the deduction is complex.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be complicated, since you must already know the type to put it in a `std::function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify type of at least one expression in ternary operator.

This should work:

```
int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    auto a_lambda = x ? static_cast<void (*)(int)>([](auto p) { }) : [](auto p) { };
}
```

or simply

```
int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    auto a_lambda = x ? [](int p) { } : [](auto p) { };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type of `x ? [](auto p){ } : [](auto p) { }` doesn't depends on how it is used after (assignment).

You have to give the common type directly in ternary operator. For example:

```
x ? static_cast<void(*)(int)>([](auto){}) : static_cast<void(*)(int)>([](auto){});
```