# c++ lambda auto type deduction

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

I'm trying to understand why this piece of code will not compile:

```
void test_fff()
{
    auto f1 = [](int x) {return x;};
    decltype(f1) f2 = [](int y) {return y;};
}
```

This is the compile error I'm getting:

> error: conversion from 'test_fff()::<lambda(int)>' to non-scalar type 'test_fff()::<lambda(int)>' requested
> 177 |     decltype(f1) f2 = [](int y) -> int {return y;};

I'm using g++ 10.2.0 with -std=c++17

However, this code compiles just fine:

```
void test_fff()
{
    FFF<decltype(2)>::foo(2);

    std::function<int (int)> f1 = [](int x) {return x;};
    decltype(f1) f2 = [](int y) {return y;};
}
```

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161219/what-is-the-type-of-a-lambda-function

Comment: Every lambda is a different type; also `auto f1 = []{}; decltype(f1) f2 = []{};` doesn't works because the first `[]{}` and the second `[]{}` are different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference between the two?

The difference between the two is that in the first case:

```
auto f1 = [](int x) {return x;};
decltype(f1) f2 = [](int y) {return y;};
```

The type of `f1` (and thus of `decltype(f1)`, so the type of `f2`) is the type of the first lambda and, taking into account that every lambda is of different type, you can't assign the second lambda to a variable of the type of the first lambda.

In the second case:

```
std::function<int (int)> f1 = [](int x) {return x;};
decltype(f1) f2 = [](int y) {return y;};
```

The type of `f1` (and thus of `decltype(f1)`, so the type of `f2`) is `std::function<int(int)>`, that isn't the type of the first or second lambda, but is compatible with both.  Compatible in the sense that both lambdas can be assigned to a `std::function<int(int)>`.