# How to define a map with lambdas as values in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I am getting the following error:

```
braced initialization of a variable declared with a placeholder type but without `=` requires exactly one element inside the braces
```

```cpp
  const auto temperature_units{
    {"K", [] (double x)->double {return x;}},
    {"C", [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}},
    {"\u2103",  [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree celcius symbol
    {"\u00B0C", [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree symbol plus C
    {"F",  [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},
    {"\u2109", [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},// degree fahrenheit symbol
    {"\u00B0F", [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}}
  };
```

Something like

```cpp
  const std::map<std::string, auto> temperature_units{
    {"K", [] (double x)->double {return x;}},
    {"C", [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}},
    {"\u2103",  [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree celcius symbol
    {"\u00B0C", [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree symbol plus C
    {"F",  [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},
    {"\u2109", [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},// degree fahrenheit symbol
    {"\u00B0F", [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}}
  };
```

also does not work as that is `error: invalid use of ‘auto` apparently. I am not sure how else to write this, as [apparently lambdas do not have a defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161372/6662425)

Comment: Lambdas may not have a defined type, but they are castable to `std::function<double, double>` in your case. Use that as type in your map.

Comment: @Blindy thanks that worked in this case - is there maybe also a more general answer? I guess you rarely would ever define a map inside a block where you might want to capture something

Comment: That is the general answer, even capturing lambdas can be cast to `std::function<>`. This will work in every single case, and perhaps irrelevant to this question, but this same thing works in C# (only it's `Action<>` or `Func<>`) and I use it at least a couple of times in every project.

Comment: If you never plan to use capturing lambda you may use pointer to function, but if signature of lambda may not exactly match or you need to use capturing one then there is no other option than `std::function` I am afraid.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::function<double(double)>>`. https://godbolt.org/z/644Phj

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bSVuCXksPKBfjN97

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
using namespace std::literals;


    const std::map temperature_units {
        std::make_pair("K"s, std::function<double(double)>{[] (double x)->double {return x;}}),
        {"C"s, [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}},
        {"\u2103"s,  [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree celcius symbol
        {"\u00B0C"s, [] (double x)->double {return x+273.15;}}, // degree symbol plus C
        {"F"s,  [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},
        {"\u2109"s, [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}},// degree fahrenheit symbol
        {"\u00B0F"s, [] (double x)->double {return (x+459.67)*5.0/9.0;}}
    };
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M5er48
some variation https://godbolt.org/z/ozqG56

So basically problem is to enforce proper type of initialization list.

Comment: I do not see how it is any better than declaring `std::map` with proper type. I can easily see how it would be worse.

Comment: I think this was OP desire to auto deduce parameters types of map.