# C++ : How to define map of priority queues using lambda comparator?

Tags: c++, c++17, priority-queue

You can define priority queue with lambda as

```
auto cmp = [] (const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) -> bool{return a.v2 > b.v2};
priority_queue<MyClass, std::vector<MyClass>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cms);
```

When I use function object(custom comparison) to define map of priority queue, there is no error.

```
   unordered_map<int, priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, greater<int>> my_map;
```

But when I use same technique(custom comparison using lambda) to define map of priority queue I get error.

```
unordered_map<MyKeyClass, priority_queue<MyClass, std::vector<MyClass>, decltype(cmp)>> my_map;
```

Error

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/queue:447:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::priority_queue<int, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int>
      >, (lambda at avg5.cpp:13:24)>::value_compare' (aka '(lambda at avg5.cpp:13:24)')
        : c(), comp() {}
               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1401:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::priority_queue<int, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      (lambda at avg5.cpp:13:24)>::priority_queue' requested here
      second(_VSTD::forward<_Args2>(_VSTD::get<_I2>(__second_args))...)
      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:507:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::priority_queue<int,
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, (lambda at avg5.cpp:13:24)> >::pair<const int &, 0>' requested here
        : pair(__pc, __first_args, __second_args,
          ^
```

How to define and populate map of priority queues with custom comparison using lambda ?

Comment: Without the `return` in `auto cmp = [] (const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b){//comparison code};` the return type is `void`. Can you add what your comparator returns please.

Comment: @RichardCritten Without return ? Its comparator, so isn't it supposed to return bool ?

Comment: Without a `return` statement the deduced return type of `<lambda>::operator(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)` will be `void` ie not a valid comparator. And without the `return` we don't have a [mcve].

Comment: @RichardCritten fair point..I am already returning bool (question updated now) but still facing issue

Comment: You have to upgrade your compiler to the one which supports C++20. Before c++20, lambdas were not default-constructible, and could not be copied by assignment operator (if they are no-captures). The error is quite clear -> `comp()`, this is default creation of your comparator - not allowed with type of lambda before c++20.

Answer (score 1):

You should not manipulate the type of lambdas. You should use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in your case. Here is what the standard say about lambda types:

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type, which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda expression. [...] 
> Lambda-expressions are not allowed in unevaluated expressions, template arguments, alias declarations, typedef declarations, and anywhere in a function (or function template) declaration except the function body and the function's default arguments.

You can find more information about this [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161219/what-is-the-type-of-a-lambda-function).